# How to verify if a file is missing inside a folder (batch script)?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have file names list inside a text file. lets say `filename.txt`
and a folder lets say `C:\Files`
i want to make a batch script which will check folder `C:\Files` using the filename list from `filename.txt` if any file missing it will give report or save missing file name inside a text file and save it.

sorry i have no clue how to make it work. it will be really helpful if someone can help me.

Comment: Type `for /?` and `if /?` for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I've commented the code in the hopes it is self explanatory.

```
@ECHO OFF
GOTO :Main
:: ======================================================================
:: For each filename in file 'fname', find all that are missing from the
:: directory specified by 'dname'.
::
:: Filenames in 'fname' are one per line, spaces are allowed in a filename.
:: Filenames in 'fname' are relative paths to the directory specified.
::     i.e. to search for files blarg and foo\bar.txt under the directory
::          C:\TEMP
::
::     'fname' will contain
::         blarg
::         foo\bar.txt
::
::     and 'dname' will be passed as C:\TEMP
::
:: Note if the entry in filename matches a directory, that will return success
:: too. This finds missing files and directories.

:Main
SETLOCAL
    SET "FNAME=%~1"
    SET "DNAME=%~2"

    :: invoke findFile for each line in the file
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN (%FNAME%) DO (
        CALL :findFile "%DNAME%" "%%~F"
    )


(ENDLOCAL
 EXIT /B 0)



:findFile
SETLOCAL
    SET "DNAME=%~1"
    SET "FNAME=%~2"

    :: Paste the folder to search with the file to find.
    IF NOT EXIST "%DNAME%\%FNAME%" (
        ECHO %FNAME% IS MISSING!!!!
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO found %FNAME%
    )
(ENDLOCAL
 EXIT /B 0)
```